# std::thread::joinable() returns false when the thread is active

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I'm trying to call `std::thread::joinable()` from a thread itself. However the returned value is false in the beginning even when the thread is supposed to be active. For example with the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::thread thethread;
    int a = 0;
    auto thefun = [&]() {
        a++;
        a++;
        std::cout << thethread.joinable() << std::endl;
        std::cout << thethread.joinable() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "msg2 from thefun" << std::endl;
        std::cout << thethread.joinable() << std::endl;
    };
    thethread = move(std::thread(thefun));
    thethread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
msg from thefun
1
```

I don't understand why the fist call to `thethread.joinable()` returns false whereas it starts to return true when `std::cout` is called. I have the feeling that this is caused by my silly mistake, I hope someone could enlighten me. Perhaps I shouldn't call `joinable()` in the thread itself?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if this is the case, then why the second call to joinable() already returns true? The thread has not finished there yet.

Comment: _"The thread has not finished there yet."_ How do you know?

Comment: Is calling `std::thread::joinable` on the current thread a valid thing to do?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There is an additional msg to be print after that "msg2 from the fun". Moreover, the same output shows up even if I add many more lines of code between the second and last call to joinable().

Comment: `thethread = move(std::thread(thefun));` the thread will start to run before the assignment takes place so accessing `thethread` inside the thread function will be a race-condition.  The thread starts as soon as `std::thread(thefun)` is fully constructed and before it returns.

Comment: @G.M. I don't know... In face that is also my question, perhaps it's not allowed.

Comment: @Weigh What and the order of any output isn't really telling what's going on in order. The only way to see, is using a synchronization mechanism like `std::mutex` or such.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ -- no, that's wrong. A thread is joinable if it has been constructed with a non-default constructor and it hasn't been joined or detached. `joinable()`. `std::thread thr;` is not `joinable()`. `std::thread thr(some_function);` is `joinable()`.

Comment: @G.M. -- you can call `joinable()` on any `std::thread` object. So, yes, if the current thread has access to a `std::thread` object that manages it, it can call `joinable()` on that object.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks! So if I understand correctly, ``thefun`` starts to be executed when ``std::thread(thefun)`` is called in ``move``. So it means ``thefun`` runs on a different thread already before it is moved to ``thethread``. And this causes a race condition of course. Please correct me if am wrong. Also please put your comment as an answer so I can click useful on it.

Comment: It is a race (so unstable analysis) - in the thread-proc the 1st call to `thethread.joinable()` is reading from the default constructed `std::thread thethread;` and the 2nd call is after the assignment has been made.

Comment: @Weigh -- the vocabulary can get confusing: `std::thread` is a C++ thing that can be used to create and manage system-level threads. `std::thread(thefun)` creates a temporary object of type `std::thread` which manages a system-level thread running `thefun`. That assignment transfers control of that system-level thread from the temporary `std::thread` object to `thethread`.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks! TIL

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks for the explanation! Now I understand it.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks for the super useful clarification! I think now I have understood it. Because of the temporary ``std::thread(thefun)`` in ``move``, a race condition occurs.

Comment: Re, "it means thefun runs on a different thread already before it is moved to the thread." Be careful! You are using the word "thread" to mean at least two completely different things in that one sentence.\* A `std::thread` is not a _thread_. That is to say, the object in the operating system, a _thread_, that represents an execution of your code is not the same thing as the object in your program, a `std::thread`, that acts as your program's _handle_ through which it can interact with and manage the operating system object. Sometimes the distinction doesn't matter, but here, I think it does.

Comment: \* If we were talking about Java code, I would have said, "three completely different things." Those would be; the OS object, the Java object, and the _variable_ in the Java program that holds a reference to the Java object. But, I'm not a C++ guy, and I don't grok how C++ programmers talk about non-reference, non-pointer, object-valued variables.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanks for the explanation! I think I have understood it now. So in fact the object that executes the code has not changed. What changes is the interface that handles the object, the interface changes from a temporary ``std::thread`` to ``thethread``

Answer (score 0):

Writes to `thethread`, due to the move assignment operator, aren't synchronized with reads from within `thefun`.